# Emacs Lisp - declare functions with a variable/varying name

Tags: emacs

I'm working on an Emacs Lisp package and one particular feature I would like to add is ability to define functions on the fly - they would follow the same naming convention, but it would help me not having to declare every single one of them manually.

To give an example, I have a basic function called exec, which takes an argument that is the name of executable to launch:

```
(def exec (cmd)
    (async-shell-command cmd "buffer"))
```

At the same time, in this particular case, I know the list of the executables that I will want to use - or more precisely, I know how to get a list of them, as it can change over time. So what I would like to do, given the following list of executables:

```
("a" "b" "c")
```

is to iterate over them and for each one to create a function with a name exec-[executable] - exec-a, exec-b, exec-c.

Unfortunately, defun does not evaluate the NAME argument so I cannot create the function name dynamically.

PS. The exec command is good enough in itself - it uses `completing-read` with the list of executables supplied, but I thought the above would be nice addition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How 'bout

```
(dolist (name name-list)
  (defalias (intern (concat "exec-" name))
   `(lambda () ,(format "Run %s via `exec'." name) (interactive) (exec ,name))))
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, thank you so much :D. Need to study more Emacs Lisp I think :).

Comment: You could also use a macro to generate the functions, but this defalias/lambda pairing is very succinct!

Comment: @Stefan, what considerations did you make in choosing defalias+lambda over a macro?

Comment: @event_jr: The fact that life is better when you can avoid macros (but don't get me wrong: when you do need macros, life is much better if you can use macros).

Comment: @Stefan any chance you can clarify what this is doing? particularly the back tick in front of the lambda and the comma's

Comment: @eightbitraptor: you might start with `C-h f backquote RET`